# Is there a Linux terminal with macro buttons?

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator

When I was working at another company, we had a custom terminal that was used that had, at the bottom of the window, tabs with 4x4 or 8x8 buttons where you could define custom commands to execute.

On each button you could define its visible name and what to execute in the terminal when clicking on it.

I found it very useful to have a tab connected to a specific feature to develop. So instead of having to store these commands in a text file, find it and copy it, I could just do the actions with one click.

Since I changed companies I have been looking for a similar thing, but have not found it yet. Does there currently exist such a terminal?